# Node JS Session not persisting

Tags: java, node.js, session

I'm having a bit of a nightmare with setting up user sessions in NodeJS. I have googled the life out of it and read a whole host of articles on here but none of the solutions work for me.

My setup:

```
app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(session({
        pool: true,
        key: 'cgtracker.cookie',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        secret: '1234567890QWERTY',
        cookie: {maxAge: 100000},
        store: new MySQLStore(options),
    }));
```

I am using MySQLStore ('express-mysql-session'). This is linked to my Db and is working as expected.Running this ->

```
router.post('/Login', function (req, res) {
        logger.log("info", "Attempting Login for user: " + req.body.Username);
        req.session.username = req.body.Username;
        res.send('Created session for: ' + req.body.Username);
```

Creates an entry in my session table for a session with an expiry.

```
| 2gbIWNuFVcE3GmjrFMEctdZlvBMufqiN | 1457713316 | {"cookie":{"originalMaxAge":100000,"expires":"2016-03-11T16:21:55.580Z","httpOnly":t                                                      rue,"path":"/"},"username":"chris.rayner"}
```

My problem is that I can't retrieve any session in any other function.
A simple test here:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
        logger.log("info", "Current Session: " + JSON.stringify(req.session));
}
```

I receive:

```
Current Session: {\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":100000,\"expires\":\"2016-03-11T16:24:15.212Z\",\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"}}","timestamp":"2016-03-11T16:22:35.212Z"}`
```

**Where is my Session data gone?!**

I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but I have tried so many variations from research I'm becoming a little lost.

My browser cookie is constructed correctly, though the value doesn't seem to correlate to any of the SessionID's stored in the session table.

Any help/ideas/suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Chris

Comment: So, it looks like the problem is a little deeper. Stripping the code back to basics. I cannot create a cookie within a POST request, it is never stored in the browser and thus not available for future requests. Works fine in a GET, but I would like to set this cookie in my Login POST function.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!

Chrome (and maybe firefox, but not tested) by default blocks cookies in POST requests when posting to a "unknown" domain. Some security feature in clientside CORS...

To fix this server side:
-Update Cors with an authorized origin(s) for the browser to check against.

`app.use(cors({
       origin: config.origin, *(I am using an array for multiple allows origins)*
       credentials: true
    }));`

To fix this Client Side:
Add this to the options in the POST header for a function.

`xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
            }`

**OR**

Add this to the Model Constructor for a Class.

`$.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
        options.xhrFields = {
          withCredentials: true
        };
  });`

After this, Cookies made in POST requests successfully "Stick" to the browser and Session functionality is a go!

What a pain!
Hope this solution helps somebody else save some time on their project!