# Express Session property differentiates between browser and Postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express-session

**UPDATE**

*I think it's worth mentioning I am running Angular CLI which runs on port 4200 and my server is running on port 8080. Could this be a problem? It's the only thing I can think of at the moment*

When I make a call to my route '/auth/login' I set a loggedIn property on the session object. To check a user is authenticated, a request is made to '/auth/checktoken'. In here, I check for the presence of the loggedIn property on the req.session object. When I do these requests within Postman everything works perfectly fine, but when using the browser my session.loggedIn property is undefined. I will paste the relevant code below. Thanks in advance for any help

**Server Side**

```
router.get('/checktoken', (req, res) => {
  if(!req.session.loggedIn) {
    return res.status(401).send({
      userTitle: 'Not authorised',
      userMessage: 'You are not authorised to view this'
    })
  }

  return res.status(200).send()
})
```

**Client Side**

```
@Injectable()
export class CheckAuthenticationService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient) { }

  canActivate() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/auth/checktoken', { responseType: 'text' })
      .toPromise()
      .then(() => {
        this.router.navigate(['admin']);
      })
      .catch( () => {
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
      });

    return true;
  }
}
```

**Snippet of login code that sets the loggedIn property**

```
if (user) {
  user.comparePassword(password, (err, isMatch) => {
    if (isMatch && isMatch) {
      req.session.loggedIn = user;
      res.status(200).send()
    } else {
      res.status(404).send({
        userTitle: 'Wrong password',
        userMessage: 'Please make sure your password is correct'
      });
      }
    });
  }
```

**Session Store setup**

```
app.use(session({
  name: 'jack-thomson',
  secret: SECRET_KEY,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: true,
  store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection
  })
}))
```

This all works in Postman but when hitting these endpoints on the client, .loggedIn is undefined, always

Comment: have you been able to solve your problem, Im having the same exact problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem before. I think it's about cors credential. I use Axios on React to POST data login to my Express backend application. I need to add these lines:

```js
    import axios from 'axios';
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Then on my Express project, I add cors:

```js
var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({
  credentials: true, 
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000'  // it's my React host
  })
);
```

Finally I can call my login function as usual, for instance:

```js
signup(){
    var url = 'http://localhost:3210/'
    axios.post(url, {
      email: this.refs.email.value,
      username: this.refs.username.value,
      password: this.refs.password.value,
      passwordConf: this.refs.passwordConf.value
    })
    .then((x)=>{
      console.log(x);
      if(x.data.username){
        this.setState({statusSignup: `Welcome ${x.data.username}`});
      } else {
        this.setState({statusSignup: x.data});
      }
    })
    .catch((error)=>{console.log(error)})
  }

  login(){
    var url = 'http://localhost:3210/';
    var data = {
      logemail: this.refs.logemail.value,
      logpassword: this.refs.logpassword.value,
    };
    axios.post(url, data)
    .then((x)=>{
      console.log(x);
      if(x.data.username){
        this.setState({statusLogin: `Welcome ${x.data.username}`});
      } else {
        this.setState({statusLogin: x.data});
      }
    })
    .catch((error)=>{console.log(error)})
  }
```

And it works! Hope this solve your problem.

Comment: Please only use live snippets when the code runs - otherwise, use plain code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using CORS?

I had the same problem, and i solved it by putting `{ withCredentials: true }` as optional arguments in every request.
I mean whenever you send a http/https request in your service, put this as last argument, and you are good to go.

You can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35945738/node-js-session-not-persisting) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35602866/how-to-send-cookie-in-request-header-for-all-the-requests-in-angular2) Stackoverflow question for more information on the topic.

Comment: I have tried that :( And yes I am using a CORS middleware in my node server

Comment: Yo need to add this in every request, and following is a snippet of my middleware use, if it may help you `app.use(cors({
 origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
 credentials: true
}));
app.use( session ({
 name: 'connect.sid',
 httponly: true,
 secret : process.env.SESSION_KEY,
 resave: false,
 saveUninitialized: true,
 store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
}));`

Comment: Thank you man but it does not work at all :/ I'm not sure if it's to do with my server running on a different port to the angular application. The angular app is running on port 4200 and my server is running on 8080

Comment: My session id is different on every request this is why I feel it is a port issue. Postman works fine but that is working on one port

Answer (score 1):

I have finally figured out what is going on. My Angular CLI was running on 4200 and my server was running on a separate port. I have gotten over the issue with serving my application with express so it is all one one route. This has solved the issue for me. If anyone comes by this I hope this information comes in handy to you!